# A test class for an interface, this test class has two http requests, so should I write two MOCKs?

Tags: apex, apex-code

When I was writing a test class for an interface, I was told that the MOCK method needs to be used when the test class contains http requests.
[Introduction of MOCK](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm)
Then I found that my interface needs to make two requests. The first time is to pass the account password to get the token, and then the second time I need to pass some content and the token and then return whether it is successful or not.
Both requests use the same method, but the input parameters are different

Then I made two requests in the code, so do I need to write two MOCK classes, or do I need to write two

```
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new YourHttpCalloutMockImpl());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same mock class and return two different HttpResponse instances depending on the HTTPRequest parameters or url path

```
// within the YourHttpCalloutMockImpl.response method add something like this
if(/* any criteria based on the request params or url path */) {
  // return token response
} else {
  // return second request 
}
```